# Routing some URL to localhost in windows

Tags: windows, apache, redirect

I want to pass some external URL to localhost with all their parameters (such as GET, POST, etc) while other URLs of these hosts be untouched.

for example:

```
example.com/path-to-file/server.php?params => localhost/server.php?params
```

But:

```
example.com/path-to-file/other.php?params => example.com/path-to-file/other.php?params (Direct routing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your host entry in the following file:
%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\

Make sure you edit the file as administrator.

You could then start a simple web server listening to requests and pass them to the original url only if they contain the parameters (i.e. file name) you want.

Comment: As i mentioned, I don't want to redirect all URLs of this host; only some certain URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. It's not a bad idea, but is there any other way to handle those URLs; not by passing all the host requests to the local server?

Comment: You probably could configure your router or some kind of a similar solution, but this is a rather uncommon need. Under these circumstances I think my solution will work and won't require much work, at least as a POC.